# How to write a method in a ruby controller and then to the ":value =>" of a text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Im very new to programming with ruby on rails.

I need to write a method for changed default values in a text_field.
It should look something like this:

```
count = 0
def value()
{
  count++
  value = ""
  if count == 1
    value = "Pre-Sales"
  elsif count == 2
    value = "Project"
  etc...
  end
  return value
}
end
```

this should mean that everytime the method is run then the count goes up by 1.
im calling the method here:

```
<p class="fields">
    <%= f.label :task_name, "Task Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => value %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
```

its inside a partial too...
I know im missing alot here and need someone to help.

Comment: Can you write a user case please? I have problems with understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: basically everytime that text field is created it has a different value for ":value =>", so 5 text_fields would have different defualt values

Comment: If you're going to keep expanding the check on ```count``` i'd go for a case statement and drop all the if elsif. You can drop the braces and you also don't need the explicit return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a feeling that you're doing something crazy / "not Rails way".

Ok, so you enter a page and your form is rendered. I guess you're using form_for helper and a :task_name is a field in db related to some model right?
What's the reasoning behind having :

```
 <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => translated_1 %>
 <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => translated_2 %>
 <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => translated_3 %>
 <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => translated_4 %>
 <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => translated_5 %>
```

?

I don't understand it but let's say you have your paragraph in a partial. You could do:

```
5.times do |i|
  render :partial => "this_is_crazy", :locals => {:i => i, :f => f}
end
```

and then inside this partial you would have your:

```
<p class="fields">
    <%= f.label :task_name, "Task Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :task_name, :value => get_default_value(i) %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
```

then you would define your `get_default_value(i)` in "helpers/crazy_helper.rb" using a case or bunch of ifs... (that's a possibility, not a suggestion or the way I would do it)

But again, I got a feeling that you're doing something wrong... Maybe I you post something more about your problem, I will be able to get you back on the right track :)

Comment: Yeh this is exactly what i was trying to do.. but buy the looks of it it is crazy talk ... but thanks for the advice

Comment: No problem. And if I could understand the basic concept behind your conditional values, then maybe I could come up with something more useful for you :)